# Unable to see design view in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqy8a.png

I'm new to this program and I tried searching for similar issues but the ones I found on this site were quite outdated questions. I load up into this file of the code which is in a form type and I could not be able to get it to preview in design view.

Comment: shift + F7 should work

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic? What does the form designer file contain?

Answer (score 0):

Press `Shift-F7` to show the design view.

OR

Show the **Solution Explorer** via `Ctrl-W,S`, then **double-click** on `Form1.cs`

Comment: I've tried Shift F7 it did work before so hence I didn't have an issue but now it does nothing, I try the solution explorer and there is nothing in there to be found its empty.

Comment: Chances are you didn't open the whole project or solution.  Have you checked it?

Comment: Ah thank you that was what I was doing wrong, such a newbie. Thanks for all your help to everyone that replied!